# c++ two threads, sharing a few integer variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio

I'm coding an audio effects plugin, and I'm fairly new-ish to C++.

I have a few read / write heads for some buffers that need to be shared across two threads (one audio processing thread, one FFT / analyzation thread).

For most all of these ints (indexes into buffers), I have figured a way to only need one thread to write, and the other can simply read. One read head however, will need to be writeable from both threads.

My naive question about C++ is: what types should I use for these integer variables?

1. int volatile?
2. [std::atomic_int](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) ?

Final question: for the integers which are only writeable in one place, can I get away with just casting them as `const` within those read threads?

Thanks!

Comment: `volatile` is not a thread synchronization primative.  Never use `volatile` to guarantee thread synchronization.  As far as what to actually use, I'd have to see the code to make any recommendation but `atomic_int` is probably a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. int volatile?

No. You need synchronisation across threads. `volatile` does not provide that you need.

> 2. std::atomic_int ?

Yes. Operations on `std::atomic` are thread safe.

> Final question: for the integers which are only writeable in one place, can I get away with just casting them as const within those read threads?

If it is modified in another thread, then you need synchronisation. Casting to const does not help.

Comment: got it. on that last point `If it is modified in another thread, then you need synchronisation. Casting to const does not help.` - why? is this because the reading thread might read mid-write? I was assuming all int writes in c++ were single op (ie: atomic).

Comment: @lollercoaster  `is this because the reading thread might read mid-write?` It is because the write and the reads are not sequential, and because the operations aren't atomic. `I was assuming all int writes in c++ were single op` There's no such guarantee in C++.